# Compute $\int_0^T e^{2B_s^2}ds$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

**Q1)**  Let $(B_t)_t$ the Brownian motion. How can I compute $$\int_0^T e^{2B_s^4}ds\ \ ?$$

I'm sorry, I'm a novice in this kind of thing. Since I don't know $B_s$, I can't conclude.

**Q2)** An other question, if $f(X_s)$ for $f$ a continuous function and a continuous stochastic process $(X_s)_s$, do we always have $$\mathbb E\int_0^T f(X_s)ds=\int_0^T \mathbb E[f(X_s)]ds\ \ \ ?$$

I would say yes. Indeed, we have that $f$ continuous and $s\longmapsto X_s$ continuous. Therefore, $f(B_s)$ continuous, and thus integrable over $[0,T]$. Therefore, using fubini we can conclude. Is my justification correct ?

Comment: There is nothing to compute in Q1, the integral itself is just a random variable (the limiting sum of many log-normal random variables). In Q2 yes you need to check the condition in order to exchange the order of limits / integrals.

Comment: About the first question. It is an integral of random process. That is if we fix some outcome (some path $\omega$), we will have a function. Depending on what $\omega$ we fix, the only thing is that it can be itegrated, but we don't know what it will come to. So we should understand it as whole. It is as the sum of lognomormal distribution. (as Reimann integral can be iterpreted something like a sum). So it is distributed as a sum of lognormal distribution. And that's all you can say.